# HTML div tag displays as inline

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a navbar made with a `div` element.

For some reason, the navbar displays **outside** its containing div.

Moreover, it behaves as **inline**, i.e. it does not spread across the width of the containing div, but ends the right after the last element it contains. Any following element will be displayed immediately to its right side, on the same line.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="imgs\coolPic.jpg />"
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Foobar</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    ...more body stuff...
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
background-color: #cccccc;
}
#nav {
background-color: #cccccc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li {
float:left;
display:block;
}
#nav ul li a:link,
#nav ul li a:visited
{
display:block;
padding: 8px 12px;
background-color: #cccccc;
text-decoration: none;
color: #111111;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
background-color: #111111;
color: #cccccc;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
float:none;
display:block;
}
#nav ul li ul li a:link,
#nav ul li ul li a:visited{
color:#444;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 10px;
clear:both;
border-bottom:solid 1px #DEDEDE;
}
#nav ul li ul li a:hover{
color:#3B5998;
}
.submenu {
position: absolute;
width: 160px;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #2E4B88;
border-top: none;
display: none;
line-height: 26px;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

...And, in case you were wondering, here's the jquery that makes the navbar work properly:

```
function nav(){
    $('div#nav ul li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').show();
    });

    $('div#nav ul li').mouseleave(function() {
    $('div#nav ul li ul').hide();
    });

    $('div#nav ul li ul').mouseleave(function() {
    $('div#nav ul li ul').hide();;
    });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
    nav();
    });
```

(Credit notes: I found the jquery [here](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-implement-perfect-multi-level.html).)

I tried playing around with the CSS `position` properties of the `header` and `div #nav` elements, but it didn't help much.

The problem occurs in Firefox, Chrome and IE alike.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: are you using a doctype and validating your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from your `#nav` and add `overflow: hidden`. If I understood your problem correctly, it should solve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pcth2/

Answer (score 1):

your image tag is wrong

change `<img src="imgs\coolPic.jpg />" to <img src="imgs\coolPic.jpg" />`

look at this http://jsfiddle.net/4fND9/1/